# How to suspend and resume an ASIHttpRequest for upload (not for download)?

Tags: macos, cocoa, file-upload, asihttprequest, nsurlrequest

In my code, I am sending an `ASIHTTPRequest`, in which I am sending the file as an `NSData` object. I have to provide the options of suspend and resume for the upload of a file. Is there any way to do that? I found the code for resume of download, but it can not be used for upload.

If it is not possible using `ASIHTTPRequest`, then is there any way to do that using `NSURLRequest` or in any other way in Cocoa for Mac OS X app (not for iPhone).

Thanks

Comment: whether suspend and resume for upload is possible depends on whther the server supports it... what http method are you using for upload (POST versus PUT) ?

Comment: @Yahia I am using POST method. And server supports the suspend and resume. But, I do not know what code to write in COCOA for this.

Comment: IIRC  `POST` doesn't support suspend and resume (according to HTTP standard)... this means that this is "non-standard" in which case I could only speculate and you are better off checking the documentation of that server on how to implement it

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Yes, you are right. I need to check on the server for its implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting Yahia's comment as this is the correct answer:

IIRC POST doesn't support suspend and resume (according to HTTP standard)... this means that this is "non-standard" in which case I could only speculate and you are better off checking the documentation of that server on how to implement it